# ¿Cómo hacer una lista de referencias con C# en un entorno seguro?

Tags: c#, paso-por-referencia

Tengo una serie de variables boleanas *bool A, B, C ......Z*
Y me gustaría hacer que cuando una tome valor TRUE todas las demás tengan valor FALSE. Y me gustaría hacerlo de alguna forma sencilla.

Lo que se me ha ocurrido es tener una lista de referencias a esas variables y buscar la coincidencia para luego cambiar su valor... he intentado usar "ref" pero me da error.

```
public List<ref bool> boolRefList = new List<ref bool>(); //--> da error
public List<bool ref> boolRefList = new List<bool ref>();//--> da error
```

Dejo el código completo de lo que estoy intentando hacer a continuación:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
//------------------------------
public class ValueChanger
{
    public bool A, B, C, D, E, F, G;

    public List<System.Object> boolRefList = new List<System.Object>();

    public ValueChanger()
    {
        boolRefList.Add(ref A);
        boolRefList.Add(ref B);
        boolRefList.Add(ref C);
        boolRefList.Add(ref D);
        boolRefList.Add(ref E);
        boolRefList.Add(ref F);
        boolRefList.Add(ref G);
    }

    public void Change(ref bool boolean)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boolRefList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (boolRefList[i] == boolean && (bool)*boolean == true)//
            {
                ;
            }
            else
            {
               (bool)*boolRefList[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
///-------------------------------------------------- 
public class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ValueChanger vc = new ValueChanger();

        vc.A = true;
        vc.D = true;
        vc.G = true;
        
        vc.Change(vc.D);

        Console.Write(" A=" + vc.A + " B=" + vc.B + " C=" + vc.C + " D=" + vc.D + " F=" + vc.F + " G=" + vc.G);///

    }
}
///-------------------------------------------------- 
//C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe bool.cs
///--------------------------------------------------
```

El código anterior me está dando un monton de errores. El resultado que en el caso del ejemplo busco obtener es que todas las variables sean falsas escepto vc.D

¿Cómo puedo hacer una lista con las referencias a esas variables y poder podificar su valor?
Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar lo siguiente

```
List<bool> valores = new List<bool>();

   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);
   valores.Add(true);

   Console.WriteLine($"Before valores {valores}");

   List<bool> aux = new List<bool>();
   bool flag = false;
   int index = 0;
   int index2 = 0;

   valores.ForEach(item =>
   {
      if (!flag)
      {
         if (item)
         {
            aux.Add(true);
            
            foreach (bool v in valores)
            {
               if (index2 != index)
                  aux.Add(false);

               index2++;
            }
            flag = true;
         }
      }
      index++;
   });
   valores = aux;

   Console.WriteLine($"After valores {valores}");
```

A grandes rasgos, lo que estamos haciendo es - *primero simular datos, obvio* -, crear variables auxiliares que nos ayudarán en el manejo de condiciones:

> **flag**, se encarga de manejar el ingreso a la operación mientras no se
> encuentre un true como valor.

> **index**, **index2** son los encargados de
> llevar el conteo de la posición del elemento actual, para después sólo
> actualizar los elementos que NO sean el actual.

> **aux**, es un listado
> auxiliar que recibirá los nuevos valores y reemplazara los mismos de
> la variable valores.

Luego de explicado esto, lo que hacemos es recorrer cada elemento del arreglo, y al momento en que encuentra un valor `true`, cambia los demás a `false`, **omitiendo el valor actual**, y cuando finaliza el seteo de todos los valores, *flag* se setea en **true** para que no vuelva a modificar la lista.

> De todas formas, no estoy conforme con 2 cosas:
>
> 1a => la forma en que estoy llevando
> el conteo de los índices.
>
> 2a => la forma en que no logré romper el ciclo apenas se cumpliera la condición true
>
> Por lo que si tienes una mejor solución o
> algún colega se anima a mejorarla, se le agradecerá (con su debida
> explicación obvio :D).

Nos comentas como te va amigo :)

Comment: Hola Gracias por contestar y por elaborar ese código... lo probaré a ver si me sirve... aunque me gustaría poder obtener una lista con las referencias de las variables originales...¿No es eso posible?

Comment: Podrías crear dos listas, una original y la otra que sea la modificada, estoy añejisimo en C# así que ignoro lo de las referencias amigo 

Comment: @IvánRodríguez Por referencia, quedaria creada tu Lista no el valor dentro de la lista.

Comment: Por referencia me refiero a la dirección de la memoria en donde está guardada la variable... basicamente lo que quiero es una lista de punteros... algo así seria en C++ (bool *puntero = &direccion) pero en un a lista... con C# se usa "ref" pero no sé como declarar la lista...

Comment: @IvánRodríguez claro, por eso te decia, que por referencia queda tu Lista no tus valores guardados dentro de la lista, Punteros en C# no se usan.

Comment: Creo que si es posible hacerlo... de hecho hice una lista con punteros a funciones... usando el Tipo "Delegate"... si se puede con funciones tiene que ser posible hecelo con variables también... algún tipo que sea equivalente a (void*) en C++... intenté con System.Object pero no sirve...

Comment: system.object es la base de todos los objetos de c#, cualquier objeto se puede convertir en object, pero no se aconseja, porque gastas mas procesador para boxing y unboxing

Comment: Gracias por decirmelo, intentaré usar System.Object lo menos posible

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu problema me parece que estas confundiendo unas cosas, que las coloco al final de la respuesta. Mientras tanto tu tienes un array de bool, entonces lo que haces es Negar ese valor y todos los valores se daran vuelta.

```
public class ClaseMain
{
    ValueChanger vc = new ValueChanger();
    public void Metodo()
    {
        vc.Change(false);

        Console.Write(" A=" + vc.A + " B=" + vc.B + " C=" + vc.C + " D=" + vc.D + " 
        F=" + vc.F + " G=" + vc.G);///
    }

}
public class ValueChanger
{
    public bool A, B, C, D, E, F = false, G = true;

    public List<bool> boolRefList = new List<bool>();
    public ValueChanger()
    {
        boolRefList.Add(A);
        boolRefList.Add(B);
        boolRefList.Add(C);
        boolRefList.Add(D);
        boolRefList.Add(E);
        boolRefList.Add(F);
        boolRefList.Add(G);
    }

    public void Change(bool boolean)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boolRefList.Count; i++)
        {
            boolRefList[i] = !boolRefList[i];
        }
    }
```

Aqui te comento los errores que creo que cometes.

1- Tu quieres cambiar el valor de una variable particular y ese nombre de variable no queda guardado, sino que solo queda tu valor, entonces tienes un array asi `[false,false,false,false,false,false,true]`, la unica opcion que tenes de esta forma es negar el resultado actual.

2- Deberias agregar algun tiempo de indice que quede guardado, entonces crear una lista de algun tipo que tu crees.

3- La forma de crear List no se usa ref. T puede ser una clase tuya o alguna primitiva de C#

Comment: Gracias por contestar Ramiro... pero necesito saber la referecia de la variable que no quiero modificar para poder distinguirla de las demás que si quiero modificar... pero bueno, en el apartado 3 de tu respuesta creo que has repondido a mi pregunta... entiendo que en C# no es posible hacer una lista de referencias de variables es decir (una lista de punteros) ¿o no lo entendí bien?

Comment: En la seguridad de C# por defecto no se puede, pero podes hacer codigo No Seguro. Dejame investigar y ver si se puede hacer asi.

Comment: fijate si esta Doc, te ayuda https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-address-of-operator

Comment: Gracias Ramiro, le doy un vistazo!!